# While converting the V2 to V3 using fromLatLngToPoint(), value is not coming

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I'm converting the code `V2` to `V3`, the following code is `google map` `V2` code. In the alert `sw.x` some value is coming.

```
//Google map V2 code:
function flagIntersectingMarkers()  {
   var pad = this.borderPadding;
       var zoom = this.map.getZoom(); 
   var projection = this.map.getCurrentMapType().getProjection();
   var bounds = this.map.getBounds();
   var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
   sw = projection.fromLatLngToPixel(sw, zoom);
   alert("sw"+sw.x); // In this alert some value is coming
   sw = new GPoint(sw.x-pad, sw.y+pad);
  sw = projection.fromPixelToLatLng(sw, zoom, true);
 }

//Google map V3 code:
function flagIntersectingMarkers()  {
   var pad = this.borderPadding;
       var zoom = this.map.getZoom();
   var projection = this.map.getProjection();
   var bounds   = this.map.getBounds();
   var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
   sw = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(sw, zoom);
   alert("sw"+sw.x); // Undefined value is coming
   sw = new google.maps.Point(sw.x-pad, sw.y+pad);
   sw = projection.fromPointToLatLng(sw, zoom, true);
 }
```

But in the above `V3` code, In the alert `sw.x` undefined value is coming, how to retrieve the `sw.x` value in `V3`.

Comment: Hello, Any body can please help for the migration of V2 to V3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that you didn't translate some of your calls properly from v2 to v3, and didn't check the parameter lists of the methods.  Make sure [you're using the latest API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference).

```
//Google map V3 code:
function flagIntersectingMarkers()  {
   var pad = this.borderPadding;
   var zoom = this.map.getZoom();              // Returns number
   var projection = this.map.getProjection();  // Returns Projection
   var bounds   = this.map.getBounds();        // Returns LatLngBounds
   var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();             // Returns LatLng
   var swpt = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(sw); // WRONG in original code 2nd argument is Point, and not needed, plus should not overwrite sw
   alert("swpt"+swpt.x); // Should be defined now
   swptnew = new google.maps.Point(swpt.x-pad, swpt.y+pad); // Build new Point with modded x and y
   swnew = projection.fromPointToLatLng(swptnew, true);  //Build new LatLng with new Point, no second argument, true for nowrap
}
```

Comment: I am alerting the projection value, it displays as object. How to print the object? please help.!!!

Comment: If would really help if you posted a complete working example of your v2 code, with map, on jsfiddle.