# Equivalent function for fromLatLngToPixel in V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am new to converting the V2 to V3 in google map. In V2 projection.fromLatLngToPixel(markerPoint, mapZoom). I can't find how to replace projection.fromLatLngToPixel(markerPoint, mapZoom) how to convert in V3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [While converting the V2 to V3 using fromLatLngToPoint(), value is not coming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215348/while-converting-the-v2-to-v3-using-fromlatlngtopoint-value-is-not-coming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this...

```
fromLatLngToPoint()
```